# Accessing PHP Global Variables when using JQuery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to delete a file using an AJAX call. It should be simple enough, but for some reason I'm getting an error when trying to access `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` when using the AJAX

I set up a HTML form and there is no problem. Let me show the code

This is the PHP which should delete the image.

```
$photo_name = $_POST['photo'];
$cat_id = $_POST['cat_id'];
$original_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$photo_name;
if(file_exists($original_path))unlink($original_path);
$data['success']=true;
```

Running the jquery below returns **syntax error: Unexpected Token**

```
$.ajax({
  type : 'POST',
  url : "includes/json_delete_photo.php",
  dataType : 'json',
  data: {
    'photo': $('#image_name').val(),
    'cat_id': $("#category_id").val(),
  },
  success : function(data){
    alert("done");
  },
  error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
alert("problem: " + errorThrown);
  } 
});
```

However, just using a HTML form to submit to json_delete_photo.php without AJAX works, and if I remove the use of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` from my PHP, the AJAX doesn't return an error (but my image doesn't delete!!)

I've been scratching my head on this one, and I'm not sure how to send the root to the page.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What's the *exact* error message? The excerpt as shown above has no such syntax error.  - And secondly, just because it's coming in via AJAX doesn't mean you should accept unverified and unauthorized delete commands. The filename could contain a lengthy path instead.

Comment: @mario +1.  Also, I can't say for sure, but unless `$_POST['photo']` has a leading `/` then it needs to be `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . $photo_name;`  As for the token error, post the line number in question and the contents of the line.  Make sure your `'` (apostrophe's) are not using the "fancy" `‘` (left/right single quote).

Comment: You used single quotes in the jQuery selector `$('#image_name')`. I'm not sure if you can do that, all the working code I've ever used/seen...use double quotes for selectors.

Comment: Thanks for the responses,

mario I have oversimplified the code to demonstrate the problem clearly. The error occurs with the simple code outlined above.

drew010 Yes, my apostrophes are fine. Switching them to double quotes (") still causes the error.

cillosis - The selector can be used with single quotes. It's either or.

I'll post the exact error message when I get home to cause the problem again. The fact is, if I remove the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] from the code, and change nothing else, it runs fine. If I have it in, it only runs when called from a form, not through AJAX.

Comment: @mario The exact error message is SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: PHP error messages usually include a line number. You might wanna elaborate on where it comes from. (I could make an educated guess, but we don't do that here.)

Comment: There isn't a PHP error. Its the error that pops up in my alert in alert("problem: " + errorThrown);

Comment: HUGE Embarrassment. I realised that $('#image_name').val() was actually empty and as a result was causing the error. Using console spotted this. Many thanks for your help. I feel rather silly.

Answer (score 0):

Should you have the trailing comma at the end of this line?

```
'cat_id': $("#category_id").val(),
```

Comment: It doesn't matter. As its part of an array, the trailing comma doesn't make a difference if there is an item after it or not.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround , try outputting the `$_SERVER` variable directly in your ajax call

```
 data: {
    'photo': $('#image_name').val(),
    'cat_id': $("#category_id").val(),
    'document_root': <?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?>
  },
```

and referring to the passed along `$_POST['document_root']` variable in your php script.

To find out the exact cause of your syntax error, use a debugging tool such as `"Chrome >> Tools >> Developer Tools >> Network Tab"`, run your script and view your ajax invoked file. You can see the exact headers sent and the response.

Comment: Thanksm this was a good call. Discovering the merits of a console right now! Managed to fix the original error.